# Apply a date field value to expiration date in inventory details subrecord

Tags: scripting, netsuite

I'm a newbie in NetSuite Scripting and was recently asked to apply the value from a date field (custbody_expiration_date) on item receipt transaction body to the expiration date field in the inventory details of all items when the item receipt is created.

Since there is no way to create a workflow on inventory details, I've managed to work out below codes however I'm keeping getting all sorts of different error message. Below is one of them after I click on save on item receipt.

Notice (SuiteScript)

org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getCurrentLineItemValue in object standard record. (/SuiteScripts/ARROW/Expiration_date_apply_to_all (1).js#27)

I am very confused on the difference between dynamic and standard mode, which functions should be used in which mode? Also, I am a bit hesitated on whether user event script is the correct way to go?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@NModuleScope Public
 */

define(['N/record','N/search'], function (record, search) {

function beforeSubmit(context) {

       var IRrecord = context.newRecord;
       var numberOfLineItems = IRrecord.getLineCount({
        sublistId: 'item'
        });
        var expirationdate = IRrecord.getValue({
           fieldId: 'custbody_expiration_date'
        });

for (var i=1; i<=numberOfLineItems; i++){
        IRrecord.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
          line: i,
          value: true
        });

      //First get Lot Number and Quantity
        var lotNumber = IRrecord.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'receiptinventorynumber');
        var quantity = IRrecord.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity');
                
        var inventoryDetail = IRrecord.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item','inventorydetail');

        inventoryDetail.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
        inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'issueinventorynumber', lotNumber);
        inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', quantity);
        inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'expirationdate', expirationdate);
        inventoryDetail.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
        inventoryDetail.commit();

        IRrecord.commitLineItem('item');

    }
    nlapiSubmitRecord(IRrecord);
}
return {
    beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic records are the kind you see client-side (as a rule) - modify a field value and some other field becomes refreshed and updated in real time. Forms sometimes need to have their fields filled in a particular order to prevent form completion errors triggering or field sourcing to work. For example, when entering a sales order, selecting the customer then defaults the sales tax when items are added to the order. Errors may be thrown at any point before the record save because a field is triggering dynamic sourcing (updating other fields), based on what has been entered.

Standard mode is - less dynamic. You populate the fields of the record in any order you choose, and when the save is performed, you choose whether sourcing (updating other fields from the data available) is triggered. Any errors in data entry are reported when the save is performed. I think it also has a lower  client-side load as there are fewer AJAX queries being triggered.

Both are available in client-side and server-side javascript, but some record types cannot be updated client-side and must be done server-side using workflow actions, User Event, Restlet, Suitelets, or scheduled scripts. To the best of my knowledge, inventory subrecords on fulfillments, receipts and the like are one such type.

The way lines are updated changes between dynamic and standard mode. In dynamic mode, lines are selected, updated then committed and the methods used would be  :

1. selectLine
2. setCurrentLineItemValue
3. commitLine (only do this if actually changing the line)

For standard mode, the way of changing lines is only to use setSublistValue and include the line number in the parameters.

Workflow action scripts will load the record in dynamic mode, but the load method can be investigated using the isDynamic() method on the record.

The other thing is, in SuiteScript 2, sublist lines are indexed from 0, not from 1 as your script is using. What's confusing is, in Suitescript 1, indexing was from 1. The code is using a mix of v1 & v2. nlapiSubmitRecord is v1, IRrecord.save is v2.

And for more information, see [SuiteAnswer 79715](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/79715/loc/en_US) which explains how to set a value on the inventory detail on an item receipt. The example reloads the record in standard mode and updates the inventoryStatus field.  [SuiteAnswer 45372](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45372/loc/en_US) explains the Record object and the difference between standard and dynamic modes. Take a look at [SuiteAnswer 67605](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/67605/loc/en_US) which explains the basics of SuiteScript v2. [SuiteAnswers](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com) is an amazing resource and the search is surprisingly good. I can also recommend [Eric T Grubaugh's site](https://stoic.software/) ([@erictgrubaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387970/erictgrubaugh)) which has some great videos including comparisons between v1 & v2.